# Having matrices as a cell of a dask dataframe

Tags: dask, dask-dataframe

I have a dataset on which each sample has 3 indexes (j,i,k) and two matrices, let's say A and B. I would like to groupby j,i and then do a reduction on all the samples with same j,i. That would result on a sum of matrices A_i that belong to the same (j,i), and another sum of matrices B_i that have same (j,i). However I cannot assign a 3D array (rows, m, n) to a dask dataframe column. Anyone knows how can I do this?

Cheers

Comment: It might be more natural to use dask arrays in this context: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array.html

Comment: How would you do the group by on that case?